# How rare are the "Rare drops" in Brave Frontier?

Tags: brave-frontier

The Brave Frontier wikia lists some "rare" drops from various dungeons, and I'm wondering about how likely it is to get these units.

Lately I've been trying to get either Mifune or a Dark Idol from the third St. Lamia's Dark Dungeon, and in about 10 runs I've seen 2 dark idols and acquired none and never found Mifune.

Does anyone have experience or data on the rates of appearance and capture of these 2 units in particular? OR the rates of the "rare" drops in general, if they are "standard" rates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get an elemental idol from Quests, I really recommend you to not do this. 
As you said, you can do 10 runs or more and never get an idol in St. Lamia.

So, I suggest you to do **the level 3 quest** in the event [Enchanted Paradise](http://bravefrontierglobal.wikia.com/wiki/Daily_Events). Each run in this quest will give you 5 random element idols. This event appears every Tuesday at the Vortex.

Unfortunately, for a unit as Mifune to drop in a Quest is even more difficult, I think it almost never happens. The best way to get an unit like this one is trying to Summon a rare unit for the price of 5 gems.

Comment: Thank you, in the end i've done just that for the idol, however I'm trying to get Luna. 

I've seen her a few times (twice in the same run!) but she never dropped :(